# Pass ID to webservice from angular factory

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, ajax, webmethod, angularjs-resource

I am new with angular and working through some problems.  While I know this is a small issue i'm struggling with the syntax on how to pass my parameter to my web service from my factory.  My error is from the web service is the parameter id is missing.

Here is my config state:

```
            .state("productDetail", {
            url:"/products/:productId",
            templateUrl: "app/products/productDetailView.html",
            controller: "ProductDetailCtrl as vm",
            resolve: {
                productResource: "productResource",
                product: function (productResource, $stateParams) {
                    var productId = $stateParams.productId;
                    return productResource.getById.get({ productId: productId }).promise;
                }
            }
```

And here is my angular resource:

```
    angular
    .module("commonservices")
    .factory("productResource",  ["$resource", function($resource){        
        return {
            getAll:$resource("WebService.asmx/GetAll"),
            getById: $resource("WebService.asmx/GetById/:productId", { productId: '@productId' })
        };

    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, only the case when it will break is, if you don't have value for `productId` in `$stateParams`, try check that value by doing `console.log($stateParams.productId)`.

Also you had a typo while returning a promise from `$resource` object. It should `.$promise` instead of `.promise`

```
return productResource.getById.get({ productId: productId }).$promise
```

**Edit**

If you wanted to pass variable to webmethod, it should be passed as query parameter rather than pass it in `URL` directly by assuming it. For that change your resource like below

```
getById: $resource("WebService.asmx/GetById", { });
```

And then change your parameter name to `id` as it the name which we are passing to webservice. It should be passed as query parameter, then only that parameter will get read by `WebMethod`.

```
return productResource.getById.get({ id: productId }).$promise
```

will form URL like `WebService.asmx/GetById?id=1` (1 is assumed productId).

Comment: productId has a value when logged to the console. But now issues is web service method name not valid

Comment: @TroyBryant are you using ASP.net `webservice`?

Comment: still missing that param id

Comment: @TroyBryant sorry.. I missed the other part..seems like your parameter name on service side is `id` so you should passed that in resource object in same way like `return productResource.getById.get({ id: productId }).$promise`

Answer (score 0):

If you need inject services in your resolve callback, use the following syntax:

```
    .state("productDetail", {
        url:"/products/:productId",
        templateUrl: "app/products/productDetailView.html",
        controller: "ProductDetailCtrl as vm",
        resolve: {
            productResource: "productResource",
            product: ['productResource','$stateParams',function (productResource, $stateParams) {
                var productId = $stateParams.productId;
                return productResource.getById.get({ productId: productId }).promise;
            }]
        }
```